# looking for a vim windows .inf ftplugin file

Tags: windows, vim, driver, inf, ftplugin

the ftplugin for vim *.inf files defaults to inform which says something about a Z-machine.  Needless to say, this provides the wrong syntax highlighting etc for a windows .inf device driver file.

- does anyone know of a vim syntax highlight file for windows .inf (device driver) files?
- what about autoloading this file when appropriate (versus the z-machine inform file...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The format of the Windows driver information files is (similar to) that of `*.ini` files, and Vim has a syntax script for that.

```
:setf dosini
```

To change the automatic detection, put the following into a `~/.vim/filetype.vim` script:

```
if exists('did_load_filetypes')
    finish
endif
augroup filetypedetect
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.inf    setf dosini
augroup END
```